# idapython: variable instruction references (def-use) for data flow analysis

Tags: ida, idapython, hexrays

Let's consider a code snippet:

[image]

I can get disassembler variables-

```
def get_function_vars(function) -> list:
    frameId = idc.get_frame_id(function)
    if frameId:
        varStruct = ida_struct.get_struc(frameId)
        if varStruct:
            return [mem for mem in varStruct.members]
    return []
```

And instruction references-

```
def get_variable_refs(function, mem) -> ida_frame.xreflist_t():
    xrefs = ida_frame.xreflist_t()
    ida_frame.build_stkvar_xrefs(xrefs, function, mem)
    return [xref.ea for xref in xrefs]
```

This gives me instructions referred by say - "var_38" -> `2017BB` and `2017E6`.

I found that I can get hex rays variables by doing something like-

```
def get_hexrays_vars(ea) -> dict:
    hexrays_types = {}
    try:
        decompiled = ida_hexrays.decompile(ea)
    except ida_hexrays.DecompilationFailure:
        return {}
    if not decompiled:
        return {}
    for var in decompiled.get_lvars():
        print(var.name)
```

This prints -

```
a1
a2
a3
v3
v4
v5
v6
```

Which aligns well with the decompiler view -

[image]

Now I want to get the instructions referred by these variables for e.g. one instruction reference for variable "V3" could be `2017D0` as "V3" is the register allocated variable in the register `ebp`.

One way to do this in binary ninja is for e.g.

```
for var in ins.vars_read:
    depd = [(func.mlil[i].address, ins.address) 
            for i in func.mlil.get_var_definitions(var) 
            if func.mlil[i].address != ins.address]
for var in ins.vars_written:
    depd += [(ins.address, func.mlil[i].address)
            for i in func.mlil.get_var_uses(var)
            if func.mlil[i].address != ins.address]
```

My end goal is to do some data flow analysis. And I thought this might be possible as decompiler is doing this anyways.

Comment: I highly recommend taking a look at gaasedelen's lucid plugin to visualize how the def-use chains (chain_t) are stored/used for the later decompilation passes before it gets converted to ctree. they're organized by mblock_t (as opposed to address), a micro-instruction (minsn_t) can be moved around or transformed depending on the operations done within a pass, and low-level information about the locations being affected by an operation are stored as intervals that either reference the parts of a register or memory location.

Comment: @AliRizvi-Santiago Thanks so much for the lead. I remember seeing this tool before. But, for sure, I will give it a try! thanks!